# Не работает русский язык в Python при передаче аргумента

Tags: python

Не работает русский язык в Python при передаче аргумента. Директивы не помогают

1.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$hello = 'поехали';
$result = shell_exec('python3 1.py ' . $hello);
echo $result;
?>
```

1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8

from __future__ import unicode_literals

import sys
from pymystem3 import Mystem
mystem = Mystem()
who = sys.argv[1]
print(u'orig: ' + who)
print(who)
text = who
lemmas = mystem.lemmatize(text)
# lemmas = mystem.lemmatize('поехали')
print(''.join(lemmas).encode('utf-8'))
```

Русский язык не лемматизирется и не отображается в браузер, а в терминале - работает. Если явно указать текст на русском, как в предпоследней строке 1.py, то работает. Но когда передаешь русский текст через аргумент - не работает.

Comment: Запишите в питоновском скрипте то, что он получил, в файл, да посмотрите содержимое - то ли он получил на вход, что ожидалось, и в какой кодировке.

Comment: @CrazyElf через браузер - файл не создается, в терминале - создается, содержит переданный текст на русском языке. Присвоил всем файлам в папке, права и группу - ту, что использует Apache www-data.